# Detect if font glyph is supported in Terminal's current font

Tags: unicode, fonts, terminal

Wondering if there is a way to check if a specific font glyph such as ▣ is supported in the Terminal, or else it ends up with the missing character question mark or blank box  thingy. That way you could tell if it doesn't support the character, then use a different character for that specific terminal.

Comment: In X, falling back to a different font that can provide the glyph is already the default behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481032/46395 -- edit: oh, you're the same person asking the previous, nevermind then

Comment: No idea: **which** terminal? And more to the point: why? Why not tell your users to use the right tool for the job? If they need to be presented with CJK ideographs, they need to be presented with CJK ideographs. "Not showing them" makes no sense: either they're important and you should tell your user which shells/terminals will work, with which options set, or they're not important and then you shouldn't be selectively showing them at all to begin with.